# domain model in starUML

Tags: uml, staruml

How can one create a  domain model in starUML?

Answer (score 3):

Create a [Class Diagram](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=152825&ssid=21978)?

Answer (score 2):

To create a [Domain Model](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html#domain-model-diagram) in [StarUML](http://staruml.io/) (version 3) is enough with add a class in one diagram and edit their style as following capture:

[image]

Is necesary enable "Suppress Operations" and unmark "Show Visibility" to achieve Class 1 style. 
In the image the corresponding buttons are enclosed in a red circle.